# How do I convert a date string in format MMDDYYYY to YYYY-MM-DD at the Unix command line?

Tags: bash, date, parsing, unix, data-conversion

From the Unix command line, how do I convert a date string in the format MMDDYYYY to the format YYYY-MM-DD?  For instance, how do I convert 02032017 to 2017-02-03?  Thanks!

I have tried this, but I'm afraid it did not work.

```sh
date -d "02032017"
```

This produces this error message.

```sh
date: invalid date ‘02032017’
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String manipulation with variable expansions

```
input_date=02032017
output_date=${input_date:4}-${input_date::2}-${input_date:2:2}
```

Comment: Cool!  That works.  I was kinda thinking `date` would be able to convert this, since it can convert so many other formats, but if it can't then I'll accept this Bash answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a date library that allows you to specify the incoming date's format, for example perl's [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece):

```sh
input_date=02032017
perl -MTime::Piece -sE 'say Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%m%d%Y")->ymd' -- -date="$input_date"
```

```
2017-02-03
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
DATE="02032017"; date -d"$DATE" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Error in the above answer.

Try this one

```
month=$(cut -c 1-2)
date=$(cut -c 3-4)
year=$(cut -c 5-8)
date=$year-$month-$date
echo $date
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm afraid not.  That produces this message:  date: invalid date ‘02032017’